# Even amount of space between breaks -- ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a Bland-Altman plot, and really want to make sure that the breaks in the x-axis are equally spaced. If you look at the plot below, the amount of space between each breaks is uneven. How can I make sure that the spaces between x < 400 and 400 < x < 500, 500 < x < 600 and 600 < x < 700, etc. are the same? [image: plot]

```
 ggplot(vals_df, aes(x = means, y = diffs)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(vals_df$diffs), colour = "blue", size = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(vals_df$diffs) - (1.96 * sd(vals_df$diffs)), colour = "red", size = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(vals_df$diffs) + (1.96 * sd(vals_df$diffs)), colour = "red", size = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = sort(c(round(mean(vals_df$diffs), 1), -400, -200, 0, 200)), labels = scaleFUN) +
  ylab("Difference in total night sleep duration: \n survey versus sleep diary") +
  xlab("Mean of total night sleep duration: \n survey and sleep diary")
```

Comment: `pretty` function?

Comment: `scale_x_continuous(limits = ..., breaks = ...)`?

Comment: As useR stated, you should use `scale_x_continuous(limits = , ...)`
You can also achieve the same with `coord_cartesian(xlim = c( min, max), ...)`
where the min and max in your case would appear to be 300 and 800 so that you can get equal spacing